# Installing Eclipse with ant1.8 on Ubuntu 10.04 through package manager

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ant, ubuntu-10.04, apt-get

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to have both Eclipse and ant1.8 installed through the package manager on Ubuntu 10.04.

With ant1.8 installed, trying to install eclipse yields:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  eclipse: Depends: eclipse-jdt but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: eclipse-pde but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Going down the dependency tree, I arrive at:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  eclipse-platform: Depends: ant (>= 1.7.1)
E: Broken packages
```

But, installing ant requires the removal of ant1.8.

Is there a way to resolve this issue without installing ant1.8 or or eclipse outside of the package manager?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use packages from Ubuntu. Just download from eclipse.org.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any reason to keep ant 1.8? If not, remove it first and then try the same again after you install ant 1.7.1.

Comment: Yes, ant1.8 is required in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I personally never install any java development tools from repository, because it gives you all kind of problems, such as version incompatibility, difficulties to upgrade etc. Most of the java tools, IDEs, app servers are available for download in zip archives, so you just have to unzip it, set up environment variables and you're ready to go!